# Find files created by UID during last 5 minutes

Tags: files, find, file-search

Is it possible to scan entire filesystem (or some recursively some directory) for files created by user with specific `$UID` created during last `5` minutes ?

For examle, `show me files from /home/ which be created by root during last 5 minutes ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, try :

```
find /home -uid 0 -mmin -5 -print
```

the final `-print` is not mandatory, it depends of your implementation of [find](/questions/tagged/find).